# menu control with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, menu

I upgraded it with IE8 from IE7, but it was in a situation that "a list did not appear" even if I assigned mouse cursor to bill of fare control. It is each item of the list part of the bill of fare precisely. The square part of the whole list displays it.

this is a code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
<Items>
<asp:MenuItem Text="setting" Value="setting">
<asp:MenuItem Text="date time setting" Value="new value" NavigateUrl="~/TimeTable.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="holder setting" Value="holder setting" NavigateUrl="~/Settei2.aspx" Selected="True"></asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
<DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
<DynamicMenuStyle BorderColor="#FF80FF" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
<StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
<StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
<DynamicItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("Text") %>
</DynamicItemTemplate>
<DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
<StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Menu>
```

What will this do? I can display it when I try it with other models (IE7).
I have to return it to IE7, Please helpme
Please help me 
Windows Vista IE8 VS2005 C#

Answer (score 1):

Add this in head tag of HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```